# How do I add Django-Filer to the Django CMS toolbar?

Tags: django, django-cms

On the [Django CMS demo](https://github.com/divio/django-cms-demo) they have something called a "Media Library" which takes you right to the [Django Filer](https://github.com/divio/django-filer).

How do I put this on the tool bar? I can go to it easily through the admin but not get an option for the toolbar.

Comment: Maybe you could fork the Filer into your project and then follow these steps?: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/toolbar.html

Comment: And if you don't want to fork Filer, just create a `cms_toolbar.py` somewhere in your project which registers the necessary views within Filer to your toolbar. That'd be the simple approach.